# Backup and restore from mongodb pod to mongo atlas

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongoose

I am running mongodb as pod now want to migrate from pod to mongo atlas. I created mongo backup using mongodump command "dump" folder got created automatically in my present directory

In Mongo Atlas network access is 0.0.0.0/0, staging database not created in mongo atlas updated connection string in my code so it will create database automatically.

When I am trying to restore from pod to atlas by using the below command

1.command

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://xx:xx@xx.xx.mongodb.net" --db staging ./dump/staging
```

Error ouput

```
2023-11-01T18:05:33.552+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2023-11-01T18:05:33.553+0000    building a list of collections to restore from dump/staging dir
2023-11-01T18:05:33.554+0000    Failed: staging.authentication: error reading database: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: listCollections. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
```

Though I am using correct username and password getting authentication failed

2.command

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://xx:xx@xx.xx.mongodb.net" --db staging ./dump
```

Error output

```
2023-11-01T18:05:39.389+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2023-11-01T18:05:39.389+0000    building a list of collections to restore from dump dir
2023-11-01T18:05:39.390+0000    don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/staging", skipping...
2023-11-01T18:05:39.390+0000    done
```

Even tried many mongo restore command but no luck.

I am not sure what is going wrong how can I restore data from pod to mongo atlas